# Using a var in my index outside a class PHP

Tags: php, class, include, var

How can i acces the $pos var outside a class? so i can use it in my index like: echo $pos i also icluded this class in my index.

```
public function CheckProfile(){

    $get = $this->db->query("SELECT positive, posts FROM users WHERE user='". $_SESSION['user'] ."'");

    while($row = $get->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            return $pos = $row['post'];
        }

    }
```

Comment: Using `return` in a while loop isn't going to do whatever you think it's going to do. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: You could use the return value of your method. But possibly you are accessing the wrong result column; shouldn't it be `posts` rather than `post`?

Comment: Do you expect only one row or more than one? The `return` in the `while` loop doesn't make a lot of sense - in that way the while loop would run only once, if at all....

Comment: These are man things wrong here. There is no class but a function. The while loop will terminate after the first result and return that. If you want all the rows either use yield or collect the rows in a result array and return that. If you want it the hard way just echo the row in the loop with print_r()

Comment: You are always overwriting `$pos` each time your code processes the whileloop

Comment: @DarylGill that only happens once...

Comment: @Martin, do you expect one or more rows to be returned? Also, is `CheckProfile()` a class method or just a function you defined in a php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everybody told you, there are many wrong things going on in your code. You should learn how to use Classes and Objects better. Anyways, here is something to start with:

Assuming you have a Class, let's define a public method:

```
public function CheckProfile($user) {

    $ret = false;

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT positive, posts FROM users WHERE user = :user");
    $stmt->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if ($stmt->execute())   {
        $ret = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

Then, from your php file, use it like that:

```
$UserData = $YourClassInstance->CheckProfile($_SESSION['user']);
if ($UserData === false) {
    echo 'Something went wrong...';
} else {
    print_r($UserData);
}
```

Start from this and try to accomplish what you really need.